# Query user /server:server (filter content)

Tags: powershell

I am working on `query user` command in PowerShell to filter the content to get the users who wer disconnected for more than 2 days on the server.

This is my result:

```
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 a_admin                                   2  Disc     20+16:56  19.08.2015
 b_admin                                   3  Disc            .  10.12.2015
 c_admin                                   4  Disc      5+22:33  24.08.2015
 d_admin                                   5  Disc        17:47  17.12.2015
 e_admin                                   6  Disc    101+18:58  02.09.2015
 f_admin                                   7  Disc      1+01:27  14.12.2015
```

The problem is the `query user` don't retrieve the data as an object format, so I can't select any column from these data, can any one help me to find a way to filter this content? Also, I am having a problem in the content of the idle time. It seems weird!?

I tried to put the output in a text file then get the content back and do some filtration, but the result is the same (`USERNAME` with empty records).

Comment: you might wanna include your script?

Comment: query user | ForEach-Object { $PSItem | ConvertFrom-String}

Comment: requires v5 if i remember correctly and youd still have to play with ConvertFrom-String. ...probably far from the best way to do it

Comment: just tried to note that youd have to parse the bag of chars that gets poured into the console yourself, powershell wont do it automagically for you :) as far as I know thats one of the drives behind Posh -- Ansgar has a nice sollution for you. ...Also that you dont need Format-Table but smth like ForEach-Object, again see Ansgar's

Comment: Keep in mind defacing questions and/or Answers is not permitted. Trying to do so might result in your question beeing locked or account suspension.

Comment: i understand that but something sensitive came up ... and this is the only thing i can do right now

Comment: @Frozen Unfortunately, by posting it on Stackoverflow, you have released this question's content under an irrevocable CC BY SA licensing, meaning you do not have the right to remove it or any answers. Please refrain from trying to deface posts in future.

Comment: I am really sorry ...... and I am sure you will do the wright thing :D

Comment: @Frozen I have flagged this question for moderator attention requesting a Lock because you seem insistent in defacing your own post.

Comment: Frozen, please stop defacing your post. If you wish to be disassociated from the post, please use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page. If there is sensitive information here, please edit out just that information and flag the post, and we can sanitize the revision history.

Answer (score 7):

`query user` produces string output. You can't convert that to objects by piping it into `Format-Table`. And `Select-Object` won't do with the output of `Format-Table` what you seem to expect anyway.

Use a regular expression match to transform the string output into a list of objects:

```
$server = 'servername'
$re = '(\w+)\s+?(\S*)\s+?(\d+)\s+Disc\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'

query user /server:$server | Where-Object { $_ -match $re } | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Username'  = $matches[1]
    'SessionID' = $matches[3]
    'IdleTime'  = $matches[4]
    'LogonTime' = $matches[5]
  }
} | Select-Object Username, IdleTime
```

This will give you everything as string values, though. Since you want to filter on the idle time you may want to convert the values to appropriate types. Using a more elaborate regular expression (with named groups) will help with that.

```
$server = 'servername'
$re = '(?<username>\w+)\s+?' +
      '(\S*)\s+?' +
      '(?<session>\d+)\s+' +
      'Disc\s+' +
      '(?:(?:(?<days>\d+)\+)?(?<hours>\d+):)?(?<minutes>\d+)\s+' +
      '(?<logon>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'

query user /server:$server | Where-Object { $_ -match $re } | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Username'  = $matches['username']
    'SessionID' = [int]$matches['session']
    'IdleTime'  = if ($matches['days']) {
                    New-TimeSpan -Days $matches['days'] -Hours $matches['hours'] -Minutes $matches['minutes']
                  } elseif ($matches['hours']) {
                    New-TimeSpan -Hours $matches['hours'] -Minutes $matches['minutes']
                  } else {
                    New-TimeSpan -Minutes $matches['minutes']
                  }
    'LogonTime' = [DateTime]::ParseExact($matches['logon'], 'dd\.MM\.yyyy', [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
  }
} | Where-Object {
  $_.IdleTime.TotalDays -gt 2
} | Select-Object Username, IdleTime
```

Comment: @AhmadInaim Sorry, my bad. There are no seconds in the idle time column. Fixed.

Comment: @AhmadInaim That is what the (now working) second code sample does.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers iam really sorry and thanks for your efforts and i hope you can understand why did i do this :D after one week i will return everything to normal but for the moment if u can just hide this answer

Comment: @Frozen Stack Overflow does not permit that.